# Adding existing .cs files to VS 2008 without VS 2008 copying the files to project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

How do I add existing C# files to a VS 2008 C# project without VS 2008 copying the files to the project folder?

When adding existing C++ files to a C++ project, VS 2008 doesn't copy the files. It simply use the file paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add note that the add button on the dialogue has a drop down. This allows you to "add as link": this does not copy the file.

Comment: Apparently this is not possible with web projects that are not web applications (just straight website projects).  Is there way to add a file as a link in this type of project?

Comment: @Rick: I suspect not. This makes sense when you consider that a web project is just a folder as directly used by the web server and no project file (or other) to contain the link. You might be able to work around with a filesystem hard link, but that would likely cause your SCM problems.